# Azure keyvault Python SDK and sign() method gives Invalid length of 'value': 44 bytes. ES256 requires 32 bytes, encoded with base64url

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk

Except the data I give to sign() ***is*** 32bytes encoded to urlsafe-base64.  No idea where they are getting 44.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from azure.keyvault import KeyVaultClient
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import MSIAuthentication
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode
from hashlib import blake2b
from binascii import unhexlify

kvclient = KeyVaultClient(MSIAuthentication(resource='https://vault.azure.net'));
op = urlsafe_b64encode(blake2b(unhexlify('00112233'), digest_size=32).digest())
print(op)
sig = kvclient.sign('https://REDACTED1.vault.azure.net', 'REDACTED2', 'REDACTED3', 'ES256', op)

$ ./aclient.py
b'QO46UZnfhhh93VCTkagtPzWj1Z-4PvmzmKdsmA4fepY='
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./aclient.py", line 12, in <module>
    sig = kvclient.sign('https://REDACTED1.vault.azure.net', 'REDACTED2', 'REDACTED3', 'ES256', op)
  File "/home/dev/hsm/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/keyvault/v7_0/key_vault_client.py", line 1022, in sign
    raise models.KeyVaultErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.keyvault.v7_0.models.keyvault.v7_0.models.key_vault_error_py3.KeyVaultErrorException: (BadParameter) Invalid length of 'value': 44 bytes. ES256 requires 32 bytes, encoded with base64url.
```

The auth/token there is handled via system-assigned managed identity  - ES256 is for ECC P256 key signature. R1 is my keyvault domainhostname, R2 is the keyname, r3 is the keyversion. Im using the docs from the [Azure SDK for Python - Keyvault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-keyvault/azure.keyvault.v7_0.key_vault_client.keyvaultclient?view=azure-python#sign-vault-base-url--key-name--key-version--algorithm--value--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-).  Also Ive tried python's standard base64 encode function in place of the "urlsafe" one, I get the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I believe I have figured this out, and apparently the error message `ES256 requires 32 bytes, encoded with base64url` is a just a bad red herring here, apparently just not applicable to the SDK and I think that message is only there to support the REST API for sign:

If you look at the [SDK example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-keyvault/tests/test_keys.py) for the sign() function, look at line 344.  It is using a variable called 'digest' as the bytes to pass as the value to the sign() function.  up at line 337 is where this digest gets created, and we all know these digests are 32byte binary type.

So despite that error, this sign() function should not base64encode the data first.  Im nearly 100% sure that the error is there to support the REST API, which does use base64encoded strings to represent the 32bytes data to be signed, where that base64url string ends up being 44 *characters*  in length.

`DOH

Comment: Hi I am facing same issue. when I pass raw tx e.g `eb8085037e11d60082520894654b464b06c40c3eb6f2f8e3cf5d7ee4e0aa34bf87038d7ea4c68000801c8080` it throw the error.